# Universal Turing Machine with an Oracle

Tags: logic, computability

(Note: For convenience, I'm phrasing this in terms of computer programs rather than Turing machines.)  Consider computer program P which does the following:

1. It asks the user to enter the code of a computer program
2. It consults an oracle to find out if there is any possibility that it will not halt if it runs the computer program in question.
3. If the oracle tells it that it may not halt if it runs the program, then it outputs "ERROR" and halts.
4. If the oracle tells it that it is guaranteed to halt if it runs the program, then it runs the program.

Now the question is, is P guaranteed to halt?  Suppose it is guaranteed to halt, and let the code for P be c.  Then the user can run P, and when prompted he can enter c, and then P will be run again, and when prompted the user can again enter c, and then P will be run again, and the user can enter c, etc.  So P is not guaranteed to halt.

But if P is not guaranteed to halt, then if the user enters c, P will just output "ERROR" and then halt.  Thus P is guaranteed to halt.  So what's going on?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: Naive question: *"But if P is not guaranteed to halt, then if the user enters c, P will just output "ERROR" and then halt. Thus P is guaranteed to halt. So what's going on?"*

Doesn't that just imply that $P$ is guaranteed to halt on this particular input $c=\langle P \rangle$ (and nothing is said about all possible other ones), so that there is no actual contradiction?

Comment: @ClementC. If P is guaranteed to halt on input c, then it is automatically guaranteed to halt on all inputs.  Think about it; if the user inputs c, then P will run P, and then the user can enter any input they want.  So if there was an input on which P would not halt, then the user could enter that input after they enter c, and thus P would not be guaranteed to halt on input c.

Comment: Step 2 is not fully specified. Are you talking only about non-oracle programs? In that case, you cannot pass P to itself. Are you talking about oracle programs? Then you cannot "run" them, you can only run them with an oracle attached. SO then you have to specify which oracle(s) are being used for the program that is being simulated, in order for step (2) to make sense (and step (4) has the same problem: you cannot just "run" an oracle program).

Comment: @CarlMummert We have a computer that is connected to an oracle, and any program running on the computer is able to make calls on the oracle, just like a computer program can get keyboard or mouse input from a user.

Comment: @Keshav Srinivasan: So in step 2 you are trying to use an oracle that tells whether arbitrary programs running *with that same oracle* will halt on every input? The problem with that idea is there is no such oracle. To see (at least) that there is a problem with trying to make that oracle, start by trying to give a precise and non-circular definition of the oracle that you have in mind for step 2.

Comment: @CarlMummert This is what the oracle does: it foresee all possible futures that could occur if P ran the program in question, and it determines whether there is any possible future in which P does not halt.

Comment: @Keshav Srinivasan: you are again saying "if P ran the program in question", but as I said you have to be explicit about the oracle every time you talk about running an oracle program. Are you trying to say: "the oracle forsees all possible futures that could occur if P ran the program in question *on that same oracle*"?

Comment: @CarlMummert I intend for any program run by P to have access to the oracle.  The oracle foresees all possible futures in which P runs the program in question, on the computer that has access to the oracle.

Comment: @ClementC. Sorry, I gave you a somewhat bad explanation above about the reasoning.  Here's a better explanation.  For any k, either the program generated by k is guaranteed to halt, in which case P is guaranteed to halt on input k, or the program generated by k is NOT guaranteed to halt, in which case P outputs "ERROR" and halts.  So either way, P is guaranteed to halt for any k.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is a little different: your "oracle" is too powerful. I believe valid computational models have well-founded oracles, in some sense—an oracle can't predict its own behavior.

**Edit:** The halting problem applies to oracles too. Suppose you had an oracle machine (a Turing machine hooked up to an oracle in some fashion) that took as input a description of a Turing machine designed to be hooked up to the same oracle and determine whether that machine, hooked up to that oracle, would halt. Proceed along the same lines as the usual halting problem proof to demonstrate a contradiction.

Comment: This is a good point, too, since you can't really define the 'source code' for an oracle.

Comment: @qaphla Why would you need "Source code" for the oracle?  You just have the computer hooked up to an oracle (just like a computer being hooked up to a mouse), and you have a way to tell a program to access the oracle.  In fact, the oracle need not be some mysterious black box; it can be a human mathematician who examines the program and figures out whether it will necessarily halt on all possible inputs

Comment: One could also take this argument as a proof that no such oracle can actually exist. The usual proof of the halting theorem can be phrased exactly this way.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that P is guaranteed to halt on any *finite* input, which is where your proof that this is impossible breaks down, as you give P an infinite input.

It would be impossible to guarantee that P halts on any input, as if its input is infinitely long, then even if P does nothing but read in the input and pass it to the oracle, it will not halt.

Edit: While I believe the above is correct when the oracle cannot act on itself, the bigger issue here is that this oracle cannot exist if you expect it to work on programs using itself.

Comment: The question the oracle answers is not whether the machine halts for a specified input stream, but whether it halts for *all* input streams. This is something the most sacred and magical oracle of guaranteed-to-halt-regardless-of-input will have no trouble doing, although the task is probably beyond the limited powers of the apprentice, guaranteed-to-halt-on-blank-tape oracle (I would imagine).

Comment: I don't think infinite input is an issue.  Instead of asking the user to keep providing inputs, we can make it more like a Turing machine by asking the user to enter a comma-delineated, possibly infinitely long string.  So the user will enter something of the form "x,y,z,w,...", where each x, y, z, etc. are finite strings.  The program will read up to the first comma, then if it needs further input for program it's running, it will read up the second comma, and then if it need further input for a program it's running within that, it will read up to the third comma, etc.

Comment: @dfeuer In that case, the answer just becomes that P is not guaranteed to halt, and then, while P(c) may halt, there exists some input k such that P(k) does not halt.  Keshav: I think that the above solution also solves your problem.

Comment: @qaphla Suppose there was some input k such that P is not guaranteed to halt on k.  Then you could input c, and then when P runs itself you can input k.  So that would mean that P is not guaranteed to halt on c.

Comment: @Keshav I never said that P was guaranteed to halt on c, merely that it could halt on c without causing a contradiction.

Comment: @qaphla I don't see how your comment above resolves my problem at all.  If you think that P is not guaranteed to halt on all inputs, then that means that the program will simply output "ERROR" if you input c.  And that means that the program is guaranteed to halt on c, which implies that it is guaranteed to halt on all inputs.  So we have a contradiction.

Comment: The idea is that P is not guaranteed to halt on all inputs. Therefore, P(c) will output "ERROR" and halt. However, this in no way guarantees that for all k, P(k) halts.

Comment: @qaphla Here is a very simple argument for why P is guaranteed to halt at all inputs: if P is not guaranteed to halt if it runs the program generated by k, then P will output "ERROR" and then halt if you input k.  Therefore, it must be guaranteed to halt on all inputs.

Comment: The issue with that is that there could exist some k (For example, the string consisting of infinitely many 1s), such that P will not halt, as it first needs to read in k and pass it to the oracle. Thus, even if reading in k in its entirety would logically cause P to halt, since k cannot be read in a finite amount of time, P will not halt on k.

Comment: @qaphla I addressed the infinite issue in a previous comment to you.  We can require that, even if the user wants to make an infinite input, the input needs to be comma-delineated, i.e. of the form "x1, x2, x3, ... ", where x1, x2, etc. are finite strings.  If P needs only one input, then it will only read up to the first comma, and thus will only use x1.  If P runs a program that also needs an input, it will use x2.  If P runs a program that itself runs a program, and that program needs an input, then it will use x3, etc.  That way P will never have to read in an infinitely long string.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9827/discussion-between-qaphla-and-keshav-srinivasan)

Comment: @qaphla I responded to your latest message in chat.

Comment: @qaphla Did you see my latest chat?